# Should a method return Class or Class<?>?

Tags: java, generics

The [Java Guidelines for Wildcard Use](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/wildcardGuidelines.html) says:

> Using a wildcard as a return type should be avoided because it forces programmers using the code to deal with wildcards.

The `Object` `getClass` method returns a `Class<?>`. The various methods in `Class` accept a `Class<?>` and if you pass in a `Class` the compiler returns an unchecked warning. This leads me to think that always using `Class<?>` is preferable.

If I have a method which returns a `Class`, and I don't know how that object will be used, which type should I return `Class` or `Class<?>`? Why? Are there any scenarios in which I might want to return simply `Class`?

Comment: @CPerkins, as I understand the quote you provided, they are talking about the four bullet points above. It goes on to give a "guideline" for return types in the quote I provided in my question. It is not only getClass, but the unchecked warnings when using Class methods which has be questioning this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `MyType<?>` is always preferable to using a raw `MyType` (and this extends to `Class`).  The guidelines take it as a given that new code will not use raw types, which are only supported for backwards compatibility.  They are not suggesting you abandon generics when `?` is the best you can do.

By using the wildcard parameter, the compile-time type safety guarantees of generics still hold.  These guarantees only exist in the *absence* of casts and raw types.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to return a type that is generic then using a wildcard is definitely preferable to using a raw type - if you start using raw types in your code then that effectively switches off all the other type safety checks you would gain from using generics properly.

The guideline says wildcards *should* be avoided, not that they *must* not be used.  You should use the most specific type that makes sense in a given scenario, which may be a concrete instantiation of the type parameters, a bounded `extends` or `super` wildcard, or an unbounded wildcard, but any of these is a better choice than a raw type.